# My renderscript path is not seen

Tags: android, renderscript

:2:10: fatal: 'rs_core.rsh' file not found

I get the above error with the Android May 22 version when writing renderscripts. I tried to re-install the Android bundle but I keep getting this error. I have a renderscript include folder but my path is not finding it. I copied rs_core.rsh to my project folder and it found it but now I am missing other include files. I reviewed my build.xml and it has the patch that points to the RenderScript folder.

Where is the sdk.dir defined? I read that it should be in local.properties but I cannot find that file.

I am new to Android so please explain any java solution well.

Thanks so much!
Tim

Comment: By the way, I had to copy the compiler llvm_rs_cc.exe from the

Comment: By the way, I had to copy the compiler llvm_rs_cc.exe from the adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\build-tools\android-4.2.2 folder to the platform-tools to get it to compile. Tim